# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\pi + \frac{1}{n})}{n}$ divergent or convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\pi + \frac{1}{n})}{n}$ divergent or convergent?.

Since $\cos(\pi + \frac{1}{n})= \cos(\pi)\cos(\frac{1}{n}) - \sin(\pi)\sin(\frac{1}{n})= (-1)\cos(\frac{1}{n})$. So we have $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{n})}{n}$$

And this is where I am stuck now. How do we prove that this series converge? I read that this series does not converge....but Wolframalpha says that this series converge. So how are we gonna prove that this series converge/diverge?

Is there anyone who could give me an advice? I would be very grateful.

Comment: After a certain $n\ge N$, $\cos \frac 1n \ge 1/2$. Compare with the harmonic series to show it diverges.

Comment: so what is it now guys xD Is it converging or diverging. Also we didn't learn anything about this $O$. So I think there must be another solution....if the series is converging of course.

Comment: @Conrad . I think you have cos & sin mixed up.

Comment: @Conrad Well I then get $\cos(1+\frac{1}{n}\leq 1-\frac{1}{2n^2}$ and thus $\frac{\cos(1+\frac{1}{n}}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^3}$. But Wolfram says its diverging.

Comment: A more interesting Q: Prove that $\sum_n \frac {\cos (\pi n+1/n)}{n}$ converges.

Comment: @Tavish Ok I see. But whats with the (-1)? Are we allowed to ignore it, by just saying, the whole series is converging, if both parts are converging. And then we ignore (-1) and just show that cos(1/n)/n is diverging, so the whole part can't converge...right?

Comment: @Analysis_Mark Yes, since minus that series diverges, so does the original series.

Comment: An alternative perspective is that as $n \to \infty$, the numerator goes to the constant $(-1)$.  So the terms of the series tend towards a fixed constant times $(1/n)$.  So, since the harmonic series is divergent, so is any fixed constant times the harmonic series.

Comment: @Conrad This is NOT an alternating series. It diverges.

Answer (score 1):

It diverges. It acts similarly to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -\frac{1}{n}$, which also diverges.

> Claim 1: For all integers $n \ge 4$, $\cos(\pi+\frac{1}{n})$ is in the interval $[-1,-\frac{2}{3}]$.

Indeed: For $n \ge 4$, note that $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{\pi}{4}$. Therefore, as $\cos(y)$ satisfies $-1\le \cos(y) \le -\frac{2}{3}$ for all $y \in [\pi, \frac{5\pi}{4},\pi]$, and $\pi - \frac{1}{n}$ is in $[\pi, \frac{5\pi}{4}]$ for each $n \ge 4$, it follows that $\cos\left(\pi +\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is in indeed the interval $[-1,-\frac{2}{3}]$ for each $n \ge 4$. So Claim 1 follows.

Thus Claim 1 implies the following: for each integral $N \ge 5$:

$$\sum_{n=4}^{N} -\frac{1}{n} \  \le \ \sum_{n=4}^{N}\frac{\cos(\pi+\frac{1}{n})}{n}$$ $$\le \ \sum_{n=4}^{N} -\frac{2}{3n}.$$

As both the leftmost sum and the rightmost  sum diverge to $-\infty$ as $N$ goes to $\infty$, it follows that the middle sum is divergent [to $-\infty$] as well.